# Download a large number of github open source projects

Tags: git

I'm trying to download a large number of open source projects, say 100,000.

I first used the github api to get a lot of project names with their user names. Then I used the following shell script to download all projects:

```
file="repo-list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "https://github.com/$line.git"
    git clone "https://github.com/$line.git"
done <"$file"
```

The problem is the terminal frequently pops up a request asking for user name and password. In this way, I can not download a lot of projects. I did change the git setting using the following line:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

The repo-list.txt contains text lines like the following:

```
sakachi99/MarkTracker
gnud/rainbow-shooter
whistlerbrk/ripple
jimpick/jaikuengine
kemper/ai-contest-ruby
jmtame/will_paginate
tom317/shopaholic
JasonTrue/fluent-nhibernate
jphalip/django-treemenus
jonashaag/configfiles
dchristo/CodeProblems
jesperdj/scala-maven-example
jchris/ohai
blueyed/fred-staging
jasonmcleod/hashbrowns.js
```

Is there a way to skip the request or a better way to download a large number of projects from github?

Comment: `cache --timeout=3600` will timeout after 60 minutes. You could use `credential.helper 'store'` instead, but read the docs about the security implications first.

Comment: @Aaron Brager Thanks! let me try. The complete command line is:  git config --global credential.helper 'store' right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you instead do

```
git clone "git://github.com/$line.git"
```

then, assuming the repositories are public, git won't prompt you for any credentials. It'll also be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks! let me try that.